# Problems with coffeeescript breakpoints in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, coffeescript, webstorm

Is there anyone who has good experience with debugging larger coffee script projects in Webstorm? 
I have a nodejs project having 200K+ lines and it driving me crazy debugging that. 50% of breakpoints set in coffeescript files are hit, but in most cases I need to find a generated .js file and put the breakpoint in the respective place. That .js-file breakpoints work well with 100% accuracy. But managing at the same time js and coffee script files is really pain in the neck. Of course I might have case when there is one file and breakpoint in one coffee line works well and on the next line doesn't.

I'm using standard coffee transpiler (1.8, same with the previous versions), but I tried as well coffee-script-redux and result were the same.

Any good or bad experience with that?